Understanding Lower Bound for Measure of Intersection of Sets $A, B,$ and $C$
Let $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a probability space.
Let $A, B, C$ be sets in $\Sigma $ such that:
$$
\mu(A \cap B) = \mu(A \cap C) = \mu(B \cap C) = \frac{2}{5}.
$$
I need to show that:
$$
\frac{1}{10} \leq \mu(A \cap B \cap C) \leq \frac{2}{5}.
$$
I find the upper bound straightforward to establish, but I am struggling to understand how to prove the lower bound. I've tried to go from the inclusion-exclusion principle and write it out, but I'm not sure how to proceed from there. Specifically, I've considered expressions like:
$$
\mu(A \cup B \cup C) = \mu(A) + \mu(B) + \mu(C) - \mu(A \cap B) - \mu(A \cap C) - \mu(B \cap C) + \mu(A \cap B \cap C).
$$
Could someone provide guidance or a detailed explanation on how to approach this proof? Thank you!

Looking at a Venn diagram may help.
If $\mu(A \cap B \cap C) = x$, then $\mu(A \cap B \cap C^c) = \frac{2}{5} - x$,
and similarly for $\mu(A \cap B^c \cap C)$ and $\mu(A^c \cap B \cap C)$.
Thus $$\mu((A \cap B \cap C) \cup (A \cap B \cap C^c) \cup (A \cap B^c \cap C) \cup (A^c \cap B \cap C)) = \frac{6}{5} - 2 x $$
which must be at most $1$ since this is a probability space.  $6/5 - 2 x \le 1$ is equivalent to $x \ge 1/10$.

Seconds after I finished doing exactly this (even with $x$ being the intersection of all three, although I didn't write on scrap paper things like $A \cap B^c \cap C$ -- I had $x,$ the $3$ two-way intersections $\frac{2}{5} - x,$ and $a,$ $b,$ $c$ for $A$-only, $B$-only, $C$-only), and was about to write an answer, when your answer popped up. The upper bound comes from all regions must be non-negative and the lower bound comes from the sum of all regions is $1.$ Of course, this might not be the formalism desired (i.e. using a Venn diagram), but from this one can get the measure formalism.

From my previous comment: "the sum of all regions is $1$" This should be at most $1,$ and hopefully had I written it up as an answer, I'd write it correctly.
